# type object 'Invoice' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Here are the models.py

```
class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey("Invoice")
    item = models.ForeignKey(StoreProduct)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True , blank=True )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200 , null=True , blank=True)
    line_item_total=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10 , decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item.product.title

class Invoice(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL , null=True , blank=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(StoreProduct, through=InvoiceItem)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True , auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False , auto_now=True)
    delivery_charges = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=50)
    original_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10 , decimal_places=2)
    final_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50 , decimal_places=2)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

here is the views.py where the Invoice object is being created but it throws error:

```
invoice = Invoice.objects.create(order=new_order , original_total=0 , final_total=0)
invoice.user=user_checkout
invoice.save()
```

here is the traceback

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\orders\views.py" in post
  265.              invoice = Invoice.objects.create(order=new_order , original_total=0 , final_total=0)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /checkout/
Exception Value: type object 'Invoice' has no attribute 'objects'
```

Why am I getting the above error and what can I do to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Please post the stack trace for your error, and the actual context in which you are calling it.

Comment: Included the traceback @solarissmoke

Comment: How do you import `Invoice`?

Comment: Somewhere you have assigned Invoice to something else, look for a line like `Invoice = `

Comment: from .models import Invoice , InvoiceItem

Comment: I have a Class Based View Named Invoice...Does it affect ?

Comment: Thanks Guys...i guess it solved the issue...View name was conflicting with the model name

Comment: could you show us your `views.py`?

Comment: problem solved@EdwinLunando